# Configuring Rails endpoints with specific HTTP verbs and path params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple Rails application and would like to expose an GET endpoint at:

```
GET http://localhost/widgets/{widget_id}/{fizz_id}
```

I'm wondering how I can setup the expectation for that endpoint (with `{widget_id}` and `{fizz_id}` as path params) in my `routes.rb` and/or the controller, say, `WidgetsController`?

I know you can access `params` inside controllers, but I think that only gives you access to form parameters and/or query string parameters. Here, those IDs are part of the RESTful path, and I'm wondering:

1. How to configure things so that the endpoint is actually: `GET http://localhost/widgets/{widget_id}/{fizz_id}`; and
2. How to get access to the values of those IDs from inside a controller method/action; and
3. Specifying this endpoint is for GET verbs only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I can setup the expectation for that endpoint (with `{widget_id}`
>   and `{fizz_id}` as path params) in my routes.rb

```
# routes.rb
get '/widgets/:widget_id/:fizz_id', to: 'widgets#action'
# widgets_controller.rb
def action
  widget_id = params[:widget_id] # <- value of /:widget_id
  fizz_id   = params[:fizz_id]   # <- value of /:fizz_id
end
```

For more info read the [`documentation.`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you have to know about Rails routing here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

In your `routes.rb` put a line like this:

```
get '/widgets/:widget_id/:fizz_id', to: 'widgets#show'
```

In your `WidgetsController`:

```
def show
  execute(params[:widget_id], params[:fizz_id])
end
```